# Make new dataframe from existing dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one `Dataframe1` from which I need to form new `Dataframe2` as given below. Column `n1` will pick the value from `Status` column in `Dataframe1` if `Dataframe1.name = A` and similarly column `n2` will take the value from column `Status` if `Dataframe1.Name = B`. Also, `Timestamp` and `id` will have unique values. Can anybody please help?

Input `Dataframe1`:

| id | Timestamp | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02:15:00 | A | FALSE |
| 1 | 02:15:00 | B | TRUE |
| 2 | 03:00:00 | A | TRUE |
| 2 | 03:00:00 | B | FALSE |

Output `Dataframe2`:

| id | Timestamp | n1 | n2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02:15:00 | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2 | 03:00:00 | TRUE | FALSE |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table):

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['id','Timestamp'], columns='Name', values='Status').reset_index().set_index('id')
df2.columns = ['Timestamp','n1','n2']
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
    Timestamp   n1     n2
id  
1   02:15:00    FALSE   TRUE
2   03:00:00    TRUE    FALSE
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? If you don't give an aggregation function this should not work.

Comment: this work, do you got error?

Comment: Yes, I don't get the Name column values. result is an empty dataframe. I am using pandas version 1.3.0

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu check on `colab`, I didn't get an error. https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: `colab` uses version 1.1.5 Your solution would not work in the newest pandas release

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu my pandas version is : Version: 1.3.4 and work correctly, I say you can check on colab, but my PC is `1.3.4`

Comment: @user12252991 welcome, Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you [(see How to upvote on Stack Overflow?)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is taking a pivot of the data with special names. If you rename `A` and `b` values as you want to `n1` and `n2` only thing you have to do is to use the `pandas.pivot_table` function.
because as its aggregation function it uses mean strings don't work out of the box. You have to provide your own aggregation function. Because in our situation every row is unique we can just give the aggregation function to take the value of that row.

```
dataframe1['Name'] = dataframe1['Name'].replace({'A': 'n1', 'b': 'n2'})
dataframe1.pivot_table(index=['id', 'Timestamp'], 
                       columns='Name', 
                       values='Status', 
                       aggfunc=lambda x:x).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

using pivot_table and then adjusting the result header.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', index_col = False)

df2 = df.pivot_table(index = ['id', 'Timestamp'], columns = 'Name', values = 'Status').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename(columns = {'A': 'n1', 'B': 'n2'})


print(df2)
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? If you don't give an aggregation function this should not work.

Comment: 1.3.0. yes it worked.